# send id number from recyclerview to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

I have an activity that contains a `RecyclerView` and a button that open another activity with some `EditTexts` that insert the data to google sheet and I read all the data of it in the `RecyclerView`, I use one of these `EditTexts` to insert a number(id) for each item of the Google sheet, what I want is to make this process automatically, and I don't want it to be `getPosition()+1` because sometimes I delete some data from it so the ID's gets changes if there is any other way for it please help me thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

1. In RecyclerView, pass desired data to parent activity in callback (such as listener) method.
2. Pass data from an existing activity to another activity through intent.
3. Other activity receives data through getIntent.

There are other ways such as DataStore, Argument(Fragment), ActivityViewModel, and Bundle, but this is probably the easiest.